# How can I write a sort function for list?

Tags: c++, list, function

I am currently trying to write a sort function for list . my code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void sort(T &mylist)
{ 
        typename std::list<T>::iterator it1;
        typename std::list<T>::iterator it2;
        for(it1=mylist.begin();it1!=mylist.end();it1++)
            for(it2=mylist.begin();it2!=mylist.end()-it1;it2++)
                if((*((it2)+1))<*it2)
                    swap((*((it2)+1)),*it2);
             cout << *it1 << ' ';
}    
int main()
{   
        list<int> List;
        List.push_back(1); 
        List.push_back(12); 
        sort(List);
        return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
  error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
  error C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'
  error C2676: binary '-' : 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
  error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::list<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Can you please help me detect where exactly is the problem?

Comment: `sort(List)`, not `sort(&List)`. You're confusing pointers and iterators.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your function takes an argument of type `T&`, but then treats it as if it's a `std::list<T>`. Either the function should take a `std::list<T>&`, or you should declare the iterators to be of type `T::iterator`.
2. The expression `it2!=mylist.end()-it1` doesn't make sense to me. Do you really mean to subtract one iterator from another? I don't think that's supported for linked lists iterators. The result would certainly not be another iterator, so you can't compare it. Perhaps the `-it1` on the end is not supposed to be there?

Answer (score 1):

Your function expects a reference, use it with `sort(List);`.

Note: Unless you do this as an exercise, prefer to use container provided `sort` or the generic  `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `sort(&List)` to `sort(List)`